# c# MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore store procedure pagination

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

for using pagination in complex query before i used sql server (tsql) i can do it very ease   using **COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalCount** in any complex query it will return total count and i can use it in pagination but in mysql it will not work

to connect with mysql with asp.net core there is two packages

- MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

i used both but i don't know how to implement pagination in store procedure and return using FromSqlRaw the issue is return number of rows **OUT TotalCount INT** that i can't get it

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_articles(IN _offset INT, IN _count INT, OUT _total INT)
BEGIN
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM content c JOIN content_types t 
ON c.content_type = t.id
WHERE t.name = 'article' 
LIMIT _offset, _count;
SET _total = FOUND_ROWS();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

c# with MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

```
var result = await dbContext.Result.FromSqlRaw("CALL get_articles (0,30,@TotalCount)",totalCount
).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbf92/3) demo

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure should accpet first element or page number then you can combine limit keyword in your SQL. For example limit k*pagecount*pagenumber , k*pagecount*(pagenumber+1)-1 
There is also version which takes limit n offset m

After edit:
please include also parameters in your call (C#).

Comment: i can do it very ease with sql server (tsql) (COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalCount) it will return total count in any complex query but i can't do the same in mysql

Comment: So try mysql's RANK () OVER() ( PARTITION BY /ORDER BY) , shall work with cte expressions too. Return whole dataset then use linq to objects.

Comment: RANK () OVER() ( PARTITION BY /ORDER BY)  is not working  (COUNT(*) OVER() as TotalCount) it will return total rows not row number

Comment: Another way i often use (ranking is not always usefull) is CTE (or view) where upper part has raw data and some ranking columns, which are source for GROUP BY in main query.